# On the algebra of functions of an embedded manifold

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry

We know that we can embed a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ of dimension $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m$ sufficiently high and specify the embedding using $n-m$ relations for the ambient coordinates. The algebra of functions on $\mathcal{M}$, $C(\mathcal{M})$, is the quotient of the algebra of functions on $\mathbb{R}^m$ by the ideal generated by the $n-m$ relations. What are concretely this ideal and the equivalence relation that gives rise to the quotient? Can we understand this, for example, for $S^2$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ via $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$? Thanks.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I don't see a physics question here, and I don't understand the question as a math question, either. What do you mean by "concretely" here? The equivalence relation is the standard one for taking quotients of rings by ideals, and the definition of an ideal generated by certain elements is also easy to locate.

Comment: I was starting to read Madore's book on Noncommutative Geometry (NCG) and I wanted to understand everything very precisely. I thought that some people familiar with NCG would help. I found a book on algebraic geometry that explains all this. I understand that an embedded manifold need not be an algebraic set, but the sphere is, for which I can follow the examples given in the book for the ideal generated by the set of zeros of polynomials. Now I understand when Madore says that, for the sphere, the ideal is the set of polynomials in $x$, $y$ and $z$ that have $\delta_{ab}x^ax^b-1$ as factor.